# Recursive Make passing targets in OS X

Tags: osx, make, gnu-make

I am trying to write a recursive `clean` target for GNU Makefile on OS X (GNU Make 3.81 - from XCode). Following GNU Make documentation, I came up with the following:

**Main Makefile**

```
ALLSUBMAKES=$(wildcard ./*/Makefile)
ALLSUBDIRS=$(patsubst %/Makefile,%,$(ALLSUBMAKES))
.PHONY: submakes clean $(ALLSUBDIRS)

submakes: $(ALLSUBDIRS)

clean: $(ALLSUBDIRS)

$(ALLSUBDIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@
```

**Submake Makefiles**

```
mainTarget:
    #do something here

clean:
    #some clean operation
```

**The problem:**

I find that `$(MAKE)` passes only the `make` executable full path name ignoring targets and all other command line options (like `-j5` for example). All submakes end up executing the `mainTarget` when I issue `make clean` on the top level.
What is the right way to implement such recursive clean targets? Or how to pass target along with all command line arguments to submakes?

Answer (score 1):

The way I've seen this done is to collect all the targets into one rule that goes into each subdir:

```
build clean install:
     @for dir in $(ALLSUBDIRS); do $(MAKE) -C "$$dir" $@; done
```

You might be able use do something with the builtin variable `MAKEFLAGS` which is automatically exported to sub-makes.

---

You could try suffixing the desired action to the target, then splitting this pseudo target to extract the action again later:

```
default: $(addsuffix .default,$(ALLSUBDIRS))
clean:   $(addsuffix .clean,$(ALLSUBDIRS))

%.default:
        $(MAKE) -C $*
%.clean:
        $(MAKE) -C $* clean
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have seen this done before.  I was hoping for something without `for` loop but it doesn't seem possible.

Comment: I was looking along the line of targets and rules, if possible.

Comment: I added a possibility without a `for` loop to my answer.